# Doctrine QueryBuilder undefined method getQuery()

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

When I execute the method **getMachineSettings** I get an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder::getQuery()

`$data` is an associative array:

```
$data['param'] = 'ip';
$data['value'] = '192.168.240.10';
```

If I replace `getQuery()->getResult()` with `execute()`, `$result` contains the query:

`SELECT * FROM machine WHERE ip = ?`

```
public function __construct()
{

    try
    {

        $dbconf = parse_ini_file('.htLogin.ini');
        $config = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration();

        $connectionParams = array
            (
                'dbname'    => $dbconf['infoDb'],
                'user'      => $dbconf['infoLogin'],
                'password'  => $dbconf['infoPw'],
                'host'      => $dbconf['infoHost'],
                'driver'    => 'pdo_mysql',
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
                'driverOptions' => array
                    (
                        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'
                    )

            );
        $this->mysql = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams, $config);

    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {

        echo $e -> getMessage();

    }


public function getMachineSettings($data)
{
    $qb = $this->mysql->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->SELECT('*')
       ->FROM('`machine`')
       ->WHERE($data['param'] . ' = :value');
    $qb->setParameters(
            array
            (
                ':value' => $data['value']
            )
        );

    $results = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();


    var_dump($result);

    return $result;

 }
```

Do you have any idea why the method `getQuery()` is not recognised?

Comment: what is `$this->mysql` ?

Comment: ManseUK - good question :) I would like to see the complete code

Comment: @ManseUK I update the question with the $this->mysql

Comment: @Angel115 updated my answer - `$results = $qb->execute->fetchAll();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do

```
$results = $qb->execute()->fetchAll();
```

**Ignore the below - it assumes that your using the Doctrine ORM, which your not**

The issue your having is that the `QueryBuilder` object your working with isn't the Doctrine ORM QueryBuilder - its the DBAL QueryBuilder.

You need to use the `createQueryBuilder` function from the `EntityManager`.

```
/** @var Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder $qb */
$qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
```

Then you can use the `select` / `from` etc methods and to get the result of the query you can run

```
$qb->getQuery()->getResult()
```

If I was to rewrite your function I would write it like this

```
public function getMachineSettings(string $field, string $value)
{
    $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('m')
       ->from('machine')
       ->where($field.' = :value');
    $qb->setParameter('value', $value);
    $results = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    var_dump($result);
    return $result;
}
```

Then you know that the function requires 2 parameters to function, passing an array doesn't let you immediately see what the function requires

Comment: $results = $qb->execute()->fetchAll(); is working just fine. Thank you so much for your time ManuseUK.